# PostgreSql remote access on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I try do access remotely a Postgresql(10.3) db.

After I modify `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'`   to `listen_addresses = '*'` or the ip, I get an error when I use:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

'Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
'

Comment: edit pg_hba.conf and give proper access rule for database, role and the IP of your remote location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply remove '#' - before - that means commented line.

UPDATE: if you changed postgresql's listen configuration, then default socket connection is not present. So if you specify exact IP for listen:  `listen_address = '192.168.1.2'` then you need to connect via  `psql -h 192.168.1.2 -U postgres`   and your pg_hba.conf should contain entry similar to :

```
host    all             all             192.168.1.2/32            md5
```

and you will need to know postgres password.  if you not worried about security - then simply use

```
host    all             all             192.168.1.2/32            trust
```

WARNING: do not use 'trust' configuration in production!

Comment: it is removed the comment, was just an editing mistake; being commented works, when I change I receive the error